# Calling Javascript in Watin

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, watin

I am trying to execute some JavaScript using C# eval call.

```
browser.Frames[1].Eval("myFunctionCall(" + Id + ", 1, " + RowNumber + ");");
```

It cannot seem to find the function as it throws a 'JavaScriptException' "The value of the property 'myFunctionCall' is null or undefined, not a Function object"

Here is the back story.
I figured out by tracing the JavaScript that this is the function called when element of interest is clicked on.  So I bring up the page in the browser and execute this JavaScript.  On loading, I get above error.
I am beginner and I am not sure how to call the JavaScript that is referenced remotely.

In summary, I would like to call javascript method.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by making sure that the JavaScript containing that function is actually loaded when using it in WatiN. You could try to declare the function before calling it.

```
Browser.Eval(
  "function myFunctionCall(Id, Num, RowNumber) {" +
  " var a = 0;" +
  " var b = 0;" +
  "}" + 
  "myFunctionCall(" + Id + ", 1, " + RowNumber + ");");
```

Hope it helps!

Additionally, make sure that the function is available from your frame. In other words, that the frame has access to that function.